# How to get an instance of IntentFilter

Tags: android

I'm very much interested in knowing, how to get instance of IntentFilter for current Activity.

In other words, an Activity wants to list its own IntentFilters, 
Wizard is something that we are going to bring up, this information is required to know for the act.